# How to update weights in a neural network using gradient descent with mini-batches?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

How does gradient descent work for training a neural network if I choose mini-batch (i.e., sample a subset of the training set)? I have thought of three different possibilities:

1. Epoch starts. We sample and feedforward one minibatch only, get the error and backprop it, i.e. update the weights. Epoch over.
2. Epoch starts. We sample and feedforward a minibatch, get the error and backprop it, i.e. update the weights. We repeat this until we have sampled the full data set. Epoch over.
3. Epoch starts. We sample and feedforward a minibatch, get the error and store it. We repeat this until we have sampled the full data set. We somehow average the errors and backprop them by updating the weights. Epoch over.

Comment: Has your question been answered or is something still not clear?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9378/8560, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/186687/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mini-batch is implemented basically as you describe in 2.

> 2. Epoch starts. We sample and feedforward a minibatch, get the error and backprop it, i.e. update the weights. We repeat this until we have sampled the full data set. Epoch over.

Assuming that the network is minimizing the following objective function:
$$
\frac{\lambda}{2}||\theta||^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}, \theta)
$$

This is essentially the weights update step

$$
\theta = (1 - \alpha \lambda) \theta - \alpha \frac{1}{b}\sum_{k=i}^{i+b-1} \frac{\partial E}{\partial \theta}(x^{(k)}, y^{(k)}, \theta)
$$

where the following symbols mean:

$E$ = the error measure (also sometimes denoted as cost measure $J$)

$\theta$ = weights

$\alpha$ = learning rate

$1 - \alpha \lambda$ = weight decay

$b$ = batch size

$x$ = variables

You loop over the consecutive batches (i.e. increment by $b$) and update the weights.  This more frequent weight updating combined with vectorization is what allows mini-batch gradient descent to tend to converge more quickly than either generic `batch` of `stochastic` methods.

Comment: Two comments: 1) the update rule $\theta_j = ...$ assumes a particular loss function the way that you've written it. I suggest defining the update rule using $\nabla h_0(x)$ instead so that it is generic. 2) the update rule does not have a weight decay (also for the sake of generality), I would write it with the weight decay.

Comment: @Sobi, good point about $\nabla h_0(x)$, I am just so used to that assumed loss function.  However I am not sure exactly what you mean when you say weight decay?  Are you referring to the division by the batch size?  Feel free to provide such a generalized function in an edit.

Comment: Thanks, i realize you have used a quadratic error function, thats not a problem. Could you mb refer me to a publication that discusses this in details?

Comment: @Sobi, regarding your edit, is $n$ supposed to be batch size?  Also, I am unfamiliar with the l2 norm notation.

Comment: @cdeterman, $n$ is the number of **all** training samples. Note that $n$ only appears in the original objective function (i.e. $\frac{\lambda}{2}||w||^2 + ...$).

Comment: @Sobi then it appears you have provided a generic SGD update rule with the L2 regularization parameter (if I understand correctly) as opposed to a Mini Batch GD rule.  Shouldn't the general equation indicate the batches of samples?

Comment: The first equation is not an SGD rule, it is the training objective function of a predictor (including a neural net) that is a linear combination of a prior over the model $||w||^2$ (which causes the loss-decay in the update rule) and an error term (denoted by $E$). The update rule (the second formula) uses SGD with a mini-batch of size $b$. You can think of the update rule as $\theta - \alpha \frac{\partial O}{\partial \theta}$ where $O(\theta)$ is the training objective (i.e. the first formula)

Comment: @Sobi, ah, when I was looking over the suggested edit it wasn't formatting the mathjax and I only was seeing the objective function.  My bad, thank you for the edit, that all seems correct to me now that I see it all.

Comment: Sure, but, please feel free to revert back to your older version if you think this is making the notation too generic. Nice answer, btw!